# Date Extracted from datetime in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I have a column of DateTime and I give only the date to a stored procedure and check it against the column in SQL table. But entries in column also contains time with date but I have to compare the only date part of column with the given input. Please reply

```
alter procedure [dbo].[db]
@date DateTime
As
begin
select * from [dbo].[production_schedule]
where DATEPART('YYYY',date)= DATEPART('YYYY-MM-DD',@date)
end;

EXEC [dbo].[db] '2002-07-01',1,0
```

I have to give only date in the procedure but I have to select those rows which have the same date in the column date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from [dbo].[production_schedule]
where convert(date,date)= convert(date,@date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write as:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[db]
@date DateTime
As
begin
select * from [dbo].[production_schedule]
where convert ( varchar(10), date, 111) = convert (varchar(10),@date,111)
end
Go

-- When there's only one input parameter in the sproc then why have 3 comma separated 
-- inputs in exec statement?
EXEC [dbo].[db] '2002-07-01'
```

[check demo here.](http://rextester.com/VYA34064)